# Is it possible to reinstall Delphi XE2 completely (e.g for update #4) while keeping existing component library registrations?

Tags: delphi, components, delphi-xe2

I am about to install Delphi Xe2 update #4 - which is a complete re-install - and I am afraid of the time taken to reinstall all the component libraries. Is there a trick now to retain these? In the past it was necessary to go through and reinstall each of them with the attendant licencing bumps that this incurs.

Comment: Take a backup of 'user\software\emb..\bds\9.0\known packages' and '..\library' keys. Restore 3rd party values in 'known packages' after reinstallation and merge missing folders in the 'library' values. That's how I moved D2007 to a different box. (now, was there an additional path entry somewhere ?.. )

Comment: @Sertac, this isn't necessary to do the update; see my comment to Keith below. (And is only safe when moving to a different box if you make sure you install all your third-party stuff to **exactly** the same location on the new machine, as in same drive and folder location.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If when uninstalling,  you choose not to remove the registry entries then all your component registrations are preserved.